# I have a problem with variable's assignment and While function

Tags: c, variables, while-loop

this is my first post, very glad to become part of this community. I am a total beginner in this matter, learning from different tutorials that I've found and this is my first "program". I'm coming to you guys, since I've got two problems on my code that my programmer friend couldn't answer me (in fact, she told me to ask it in here):

I'm sure that it's an easy answer, but I just have no idea and I couldn't find any proper answer on the internet (or I didn't look properly).

Thank you all!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
// insert code here...
int num1;
int num3;
char ans[3];

printf("Enter first number: ");
scanf("%i", &num1);
printf("Enter second number: ");
scanf("%i", &num3);
while(!(strcmp(ans,"Sum") | (!(strcmp(ans,"Sub"))) | (!(strcmp(ans,"Mul"))) | (! 
(strcmp(ans,"Div"))) == 0));
printf("What kind of operation do you want to make? Type Sum, Sub, Mul or Div: 
");
scanf("%s", ans);
int Sum = num1 + num3;
int Sub = num1 - num3;
int Mul = num1 * num3;
//    int Div = num1 / num2;

if((strcmp(ans,"Sum") == 0))
{
    printf("The sum of both numbers give %d\n", Sum);
}
//    {printf("%d y %d\n", num1, num2);
//}
if((strcmp(ans,"Sub") == 0))
{
    printf("The substraction of both numbers give %d\n", Sub);
}
if((strcmp(ans,"Mul") == 0))
{
    printf("The multiplication of both numbers give %d\n", Mul);
}
if((strcmp(ans,"Div") == 0))
{
    printf("The division of both numbers give %d\n", num1 / num3);
}
{    if (!(strcmp(ans,"Sum") | (!(strcmp(ans,"Sub"))) | (!(strcmp(ans,"Mul"))) | 
(!(strcmp(ans,"Div"))) == 0))
{
    printf("This command does not apply, please type the correct option\n");
}
    //((strcmp(ans, "Sum")) | (strcmp(ans, "Sub")) | (strcmp(ans, "Mul")) | 
(strcmp(ans, "Div")) != 0) {



}
}
```

- As I run the program, it doesn't assign any value to "num2" other than 0.
- What I really want the "while" function to do is to tell you that you've entered a wrong character and to go back to the main question until you enter it right.

P.S: Now I've sent all the code I've written.

Comment: Your code formatting is broken. Why the backticks everywhere?

Comment: you should have started with basic ones first. Your indentation is not good and even code is not complete.

Comment: `strcmp(ans,"Sum")` Your array `ans` is not inizialized and it is too short to hold the strings you are comparing it with. `Sum` needs 4 characters to store the letters and the terminating nul character.

Comment: Your `while` loop only contains an empty instruction. It won't do anything even if you provide a value for `ans`

Comment: General advice: You should **always** check result of `scanf` function calls. The return value has a meaning (you find it in the man page, the C standard of any tutorial) and should not be ignored. You should also **always** enable warnings in your compiler and read them carefully.

Comment: I've just updated the code to the complete one that I've written. Thanks for the comments, if somebody could point me a good tutorial out I would really appreciate it, because I'm getting crazy going from one to the other. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @Desert refer to my answer for a full working version ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not check you enter valid number for the two numbers because you do not check if *scanf* returns 1

The test in the *while* has '(' ')' wrongly placed and it the same for the *if*

In the *while* you compare *ans* before to read it so its use is an undefined behavior, the *while* can loops indefinitely

The *scanf* to read the operation do not limit the number of read characters, you can write out of *ans* and even a valid operation name is enter you have no place to memorize the final null character

The end of the program doing the operations is missing

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int num1;
  int num2;
  char ans[4];

  printf("Enter first number: ");

  if (scanf("%i", &num1) != 1) {
    puts("invalid number");
    return -1;
  }

  printf("Enter second number: ");

  if (scanf("%i", &num2) != 1) {
    puts("invalid number");
    return -1;
  }

  for (;;) {
    printf("What kind of operation do you want to make? Type Sum, Sub, Mul or Div: ");
    if (scanf("%3s", ans) != 1)
      /* EOF */
      return -1;

    if (!strcmp(ans,"Sum")) {
      printf("%d+%d=%d\n", num1, num2, num1+num2);
      return 0;
    }
    if (!strcmp(ans,"Sub")) {
      printf("%d-%d=%d\n", num1, num2, num1-num2);
      return 0;
    }
    if (!strcmp(ans,"Mul")) {
      printf("%d*%d=%d\n", num1, num2, num1*num2);
      return 0;
    }
    if (!strcmp(ans,"Div")) {
      if (num2 == 0)
        puts("cannot divide by 0");
      else
        printf("%d/%d=%d\n", num1, num2, num1/num2);
      return 0;
    }
    puts("This command does not apply, please type the correct option");
  }
}
```

As you can see I do not have a separated *while* to only check the input operation is valid because doing that you have after to again test what is the enter operation to manage it.

Compilation and executions :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra o.c
/tmp % ./a.out
Enter first number: 12
Enter second number: 34
What kind of operation do you want to make? Type Sum, Sub, Mul or Div: aze
This command does not apply, please type the correct option
What kind of operation do you want to make? Type Sum, Sub, Mul or Div: Sum
12+34=46
/tmp % ./a.out
Enter first number: aze
invalid number
/tmp %
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!(
          strcmp(ans,"Sum") | (!(
          strcmp(ans,"Sub"))) | (!(
          strcmp(ans,"Mul"))) | (!(
          strcmp(ans,"Div"))) == 0));
```

This makes no sense. First of all, logical OR is written as `||` not `|`. Second, the `;` at the end, meaning loop forever in this case, since input is never changed inside the loop. You shouldn't have used `;` but `{ ... }` and put it around the printf and scanf to form a loop around them.

Rewrite this into something like:

```
do
{
  printf("What kind of operation do you want to make? Type Sum, Sub, 'Mul' or Div: ");
  scanf("%s", ans);
}while( strcmp(ans,"Sum") && 
        strcmp(ans,"Sub") &&
        strcmp(ans,"Mul") &&
        strcmp(ans,"Div") );
```

`strcmp` returning non-zero if the strings doesn't match, meaning this C can be read in English as:
"do ask for input while input is not Sum and input is not Sub and input is not Mul and input is not Div".